# Unable to print the resutls accordingly and write the same results in a csv file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to parse the value of some `categories` according to their `category name` from a dictionary. The category names I've chosen to parse from this dictionary are `Interior Features` and `Spaces and Amenities` for now. The follwing script can parse them but when I tried to print them, the alignments of that output become messy which obviously impacts similarly in a csv file when I write them.

How can I print the result and write the same in a csv file in the right way?

Here are the content for your consideration:

```
[{'categoryGroupName': 'Interior Features', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Bedrooms', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Beds', 'factValue': '3'}, {'factLabel': 'Master bedroom location', 'factValue': 'Main'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Kitchen', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Kitchen location', 'factValue': 'Main'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Other Rooms', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Dining room location', 'factValue': 'Main'}, {'factLabel': 'Living room location', 'factValue': 'Main'}, {'factLabel': 'Utility room location', 'factValue': 'Lower'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Heating and Cooling', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Heating', 'factValue': 'Forced air'}, {'factLabel': 'Heating', 'factValue': 'Gas'}, {'factLabel': 'Heating and cooling', 'factValue': '90%+ High Efficiency, Forced Air'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Basement', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Partially finished'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': '900 sqft basement'}, {'factLabel': 'Basement', 'factValue': 'Partially Finished'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Attic', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Attic'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Appliances', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Appliances included', 'factValue': 'Dishwasher, Dryer, Microwave, Range / Oven, Refrigerator, Washer'}, {'factLabel': 'Appliances that stay', 'factValue': 'Range/Oven, Dishwasher, Refrigerator, Washer, Dryer'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Flooring', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Floor size', 'factValue': '2,070 sqft'}, {'factLabel': 'Flooring', 'factValue': 'Carpet, Hardwood, Tile'}, {'factLabel': 'Floor covering', 'factValue': 'Hardwood, Laminate, Wall to Wall Carpet'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Other Interior Features', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Addition size', 'factValue': '900'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Fireplace'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Ceiling Fan'}, {'factLabel': 'Features', 'factValue': 'Dbl Pane/Storm Windw, Dining Room, Security System, Ceiling Fan(s), Hot Tub/Spa'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Building', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Other Building Features', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Building info', 'factValue': 'Built On Lot'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Spaces and Amenities', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Size', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Unit count', 'factValue': '1'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Spaces', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Hot Tub/Spa'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Amenities', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Security System'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Construction', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Type and Style', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Structure type', 'factValue': 'Craftsman'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Single Family'}, {'factLabel': 'Architecture', 'factValue': 'Craftsman'}, {'factLabel': 'Entrance level', 'factValue': 'Main'}, {'factLabel': 'Style', 'factValue': '16 - 1 Story w/Bsmnt.'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Materials', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Roof type', 'factValue': 'Composition'}, {'factLabel': 'Exterior material', 'factValue': 'Wood'}, {'factLabel': 'Roof', 'factValue': 'Composition'}, {'factLabel': 'Foundation', 'factValue': 'Poured Concrete'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Dates', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Built in 1916'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Other Construction Features', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Stories', 'factValue': '1'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Exterior Features', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Patio', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Deck'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Yard', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Fenced Yard'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Garden'}]}, {'categoryName': 'View Type', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'View', 'factValue': 'Mountain'}, {'factLabel': 'View', 'factValue': 'Territorial, See Remarks'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Lot', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Lot', 'factValue': '4,000 sqft'}, {'factLabel': 'Lot topography/vegetation', 'factValue': 'Level, Steep Slope'}, {'factLabel': 'Lot details', 'factValue': 'Paved Street, Sidewalk, Curbs'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Other Exterior Features', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Parcel #', 'factValue': '6610001005'}, {'factLabel': 'Exterior', 'factValue': 'Wood'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Community and Neighborhood', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Schools', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Elementary school', 'factValue': 'Buyer To Verify'}, {'factLabel': 'Middle school', 'factValue': 'Buyer To Verify'}, {'factLabel': 'High school', 'factValue': 'Buyer To Verify'}, {'factLabel': 'School district', 'factValue': 'Seattle'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Transportation', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Bus line nearby', 'factValue': 'Y'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Parking', 'categories': [{'categoryName': '', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Parking', 'factValue': 'Attached Garage, 1 space, 290 sqft garage'}, {'factLabel': 'Parking type', 'factValue': 'Garage-Attached, Off Street'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Utilities', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Utilities', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Cable Ready'}, {'factLabel': 'Sewer', 'factValue': 'Sewer Connected'}, {'factLabel': 'Water source', 'factValue': 'Public'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Green Energy', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Energy source', 'factValue': 'Natural Gas, Solar (Unspecified)'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Other', 'categories': [{'categoryName': '', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Last sold', 'factValue': 'Dec 2019 for $900,000'}, {'factLabel': 'Last sale price/sqft', 'factValue': '$435'}, {'factLabel': 'Property type', 'factValue': 'RESI'}, {'factLabel': 'Possesion', 'factValue': 'Closing'}, {'factLabel': 'Form 17', 'factValue': 'Provided'}, {'factLabel': 'Potential terms', 'factValue': 'Cash Out, Conventional'}, {'factLabel': 'Site features', 'factValue': 'Cable TV, Deck, Fenced-Partially, Gas Available, Hot Tub/Spa'}, {'factLabel': 'Offers', 'factValue': 'Reviewed on receipt'}, {'factLabel': 'Commission', 'factValue': '2.5%'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Activity On Zillow', 'categories': [{'categoryName': '', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Views since listing', 'factValue': '77'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': '1 shopper saved this home'}]}]}]
```

Script I've tried with:

```
desc = [{'categoryGroupName': 'Interior Features', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Bedrooms', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Beds', 'factValue': '3'}, {'factLabel': 'Master bedroom location', 'factValue': 'Main'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Kitchen', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Kitchen location', 'factValue': 'Main'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Other Rooms', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Dining room location', 'factValue': 'Main'}, {'factLabel': 'Living room location', 'factValue': 'Main'}, {'factLabel': 'Utility room location', 'factValue': 'Lower'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Heating and Cooling', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Heating', 'factValue': 'Forced air'}, {'factLabel': 'Heating', 'factValue': 'Gas'}, {'factLabel': 'Heating and cooling', 'factValue': '90%+ High Efficiency, Forced Air'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Basement', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Partially finished'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': '900 sqft basement'}, {'factLabel': 'Basement', 'factValue': 'Partially Finished'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Attic', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Attic'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Appliances', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Appliances included', 'factValue': 'Dishwasher, Dryer, Microwave, Range / Oven, Refrigerator, Washer'}, {'factLabel': 'Appliances that stay', 'factValue': 'Range/Oven, Dishwasher, Refrigerator, Washer, Dryer'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Flooring', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Floor size', 'factValue': '2,070 sqft'}, {'factLabel': 'Flooring', 'factValue': 'Carpet, Hardwood, Tile'}, {'factLabel': 'Floor covering', 'factValue': 'Hardwood, Laminate, Wall to Wall Carpet'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Other Interior Features', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Addition size', 'factValue': '900'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Fireplace'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Ceiling Fan'}, {'factLabel': 'Features', 'factValue': 'Dbl Pane/Storm Windw, Dining Room, Security System, Ceiling Fan(s), Hot Tub/Spa'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Building', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Other Building Features', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Building info', 'factValue': 'Built On Lot'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Spaces and Amenities', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Size', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Unit count', 'factValue': '1'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Spaces', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Hot Tub/Spa'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Amenities', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Security System'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Construction', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Type and Style', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Structure type', 'factValue': 'Craftsman'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Single Family'}, {'factLabel': 'Architecture', 'factValue': 'Craftsman'}, {'factLabel': 'Entrance level', 'factValue': 'Main'}, {'factLabel': 'Style', 'factValue': '16 - 1 Story w/Bsmnt.'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Materials', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Roof type', 'factValue': 'Composition'}, {'factLabel': 'Exterior material', 'factValue': 'Wood'}, {'factLabel': 'Roof', 'factValue': 'Composition'}, {'factLabel': 'Foundation', 'factValue': 'Poured Concrete'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Dates', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Built in 1916'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Other Construction Features', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Stories', 'factValue': '1'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Exterior Features', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Patio', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Deck'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Yard', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Fenced Yard'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Garden'}]}, {'categoryName': 'View Type', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'View', 'factValue': 'Mountain'}, {'factLabel': 'View', 'factValue': 'Territorial, See Remarks'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Lot', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Lot', 'factValue': '4,000 sqft'}, {'factLabel': 'Lot topography/vegetation', 'factValue': 'Level, Steep Slope'}, {'factLabel': 'Lot details', 'factValue': 'Paved Street, Sidewalk, Curbs'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Other Exterior Features', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Parcel #', 'factValue': '6610001005'}, {'factLabel': 'Exterior', 'factValue': 'Wood'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Community and Neighborhood', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Schools', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Elementary school', 'factValue': 'Buyer To Verify'}, {'factLabel': 'Middle school', 'factValue': 'Buyer To Verify'}, {'factLabel': 'High school', 'factValue': 'Buyer To Verify'}, {'factLabel': 'School district', 'factValue': 'Seattle'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Transportation', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Bus line nearby', 'factValue': 'Y'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Parking', 'categories': [{'categoryName': '', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Parking', 'factValue': 'Attached Garage, 1 space, 290 sqft garage'}, {'factLabel': 'Parking type', 'factValue': 'Garage-Attached, Off Street'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Utilities', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Utilities', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Cable Ready'}, {'factLabel': 'Sewer', 'factValue': 'Sewer Connected'}, {'factLabel': 'Water source', 'factValue': 'Public'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Green Energy', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Energy source', 'factValue': 'Natural Gas, Solar (Unspecified)'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Other', 'categories': [{'categoryName': '', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Last sold', 'factValue': 'Dec 2019 for $900,000'}, {'factLabel': 'Last sale price/sqft', 'factValue': '$435'}, {'factLabel': 'Property type', 'factValue': 'RESI'}, {'factLabel': 'Possesion', 'factValue': 'Closing'}, {'factLabel': 'Form 17', 'factValue': 'Provided'}, {'factLabel': 'Potential terms', 'factValue': 'Cash Out, Conventional'}, {'factLabel': 'Site features', 'factValue': 'Cable TV, Deck, Fenced-Partially, Gas Available, Hot Tub/Spa'}, {'factLabel': 'Offers', 'factValue': 'Reviewed on receipt'}, {'factLabel': 'Commission', 'factValue': '2.5%'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Activity On Zillow', 'categories': [{'categoryName': '', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Views since listing', 'factValue': '77'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': '1 shopper saved this home'}]}]}]

name = "property in somewhere"

for elem in desc:

    if elem['categoryGroupName']=='Interior Features':
        interior_features = {curr['factLabel']: curr['factValue'] for i in elem['categories'] for curr in i['categoryFacts']}
        interior_features = str(interior_features).replace("{","").replace("}","").replace("'","")
    else:
        interior_features = ""

    if elem['categoryGroupName']=='Spaces and Amenities':
        space_amenities = {curr['factLabel']: curr['factValue'] for i in elem['categories'] for curr in i['categoryFacts']}
        space_amenities = str(space_amenities).replace("{","").replace("}","").replace("'","")
    else:
        space_amenities = ""

    print(name,interior_features,space_amenities)
```

Result I'm getting:

```
property in somewhere Beds: 3, Master bedroom location: Main, Kitchen location: Main, Dining room location: Main, Living room location: Main, Utility room location: Lower, Heating: Gas, Heating and cooling: 90%+ High Efficiency, Forced Air, None: Ceiling Fan, Basement: Partially Finished, Appliances included: Dishwasher, Dryer, Microwave, Range / Oven, Refrigerator, Washer, Appliances that stay: Range/Oven, Dishwasher, Refrigerator, Washer, Dryer, Floor size: 2,070 sqft, Flooring: Carpet, Hardwood, Tile, Floor covering: Hardwood, Laminate, Wall to Wall Carpet, Addition size: 900, Features: Dbl Pane/Storm Windw, Dining Room, Security System, Ceiling Fan(s), Hot Tub/Spa 
property in somewhere  
property in somewhere  Unit count: 1, None: Security System
property in somewhere  
property in somewhere  
property in somewhere  
property in somewhere  
property in somewhere  
property in somewhere  
property in somewhere
```

In the above output you can see that this line `property in somewhere` has been printed several times whereas it should be printed once. This line `Unit count: 1, None: Security System` should be in coulmn three whereas it has got placed some unwanted area.

> The bottom line is the above script should print the results once but it prints multiple times because of the for loop.

Expected output (pasted here the variable names instead of their values to make you understand the alignment). To be more clear - there is no result for row b, row c and so on. The result should be printed once and limited to Row A1, Row B1 and Row C1. Period.

```
Column A    Column B             Column C
name        interior_features    space_amenities
```

Comment: @robots.txt--the reason 'property in somewhere' is printed multiple times is you have 10 categories, namely: ['Interior Features', 'Building', 'Spaces and Amenities', 'Construction', 'Exterior Features', 'Community and Neighborhood', 'Parking', 'Utilities', 'Other', 'Activity On Zillow'].  Only two of these match your filter and have data while the others print null strings for interior_featues and space_amenities.

Comment: Hey robots.txt, nice to see you again. If I understand correctly, every `desc` list is expected to have one `interior_features` item and one `space_amenities` item only. If so, you could create a list that contains the `name` value, and when you find a `interior_features` or `space_amenities` value add it to the list. At the end of the loop you should have a list with three items: `[name, interior_features, space_amenities]` that you can print or save to file. Please let me know if something is unclear, or if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Hi @t.m.adam, nice to find you in the loop. If you check on [this link](https://filebin.net/0ybrpmwuufh5lgah), you can find my rectified approach complying with your suggestion. Please read it through. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, in that case you could use a dictionary with N/A as default values (eg: `rows = {'name': name, 'interior_features':'N/A', 'space_amenities':'N/A', 'imaginary_stuff':'N/A'}
`). When you find an item add it to the dictionary; if there is no item that dictionary key will have the default value - N/A. You can use `dict.values()` to get the dictionary values in a list.

Comment: This idea seems to be very promising @t.m.adam. The problem is I can't really find any idea as to how I implement it within the script as I'm way behind when it comes to play with the dictionary content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the goal is to get certain values from the items in `desc`. Each value may be present one time or not at all - in this case the result should be 'N/A'. So, you can use a dictionary with N/A default values, then replace them with the values found in the `desc` list.

```
desc = [{'categoryGroupName': 'Interior Features', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Bedrooms', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Beds', 'factValue': '3'}, {'factLabel': 'Master bedroom location', 'factValue': 'Main'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Kitchen', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Kitchen location', 'factValue': 'Main'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Other Rooms', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Dining room location', 'factValue': 'Main'}, {'factLabel': 'Living room location', 'factValue': 'Main'}, {'factLabel': 'Utility room location', 'factValue': 'Lower'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Heating and Cooling', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Heating', 'factValue': 'Forced air'}, {'factLabel': 'Heating', 'factValue': 'Gas'}, {'factLabel': 'Heating and cooling', 'factValue': '90%+ High Efficiency, Forced Air'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Basement', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Partially finished'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': '900 sqft basement'}, {'factLabel': 'Basement', 'factValue': 'Partially Finished'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Attic', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Attic'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Appliances', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Appliances included', 'factValue': 'Dishwasher, Dryer, Microwave, Range / Oven, Refrigerator, Washer'}, {'factLabel': 'Appliances that stay', 'factValue': 'Range/Oven, Dishwasher, Refrigerator, Washer, Dryer'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Flooring', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Floor size', 'factValue': '2,070 sqft'}, {'factLabel': 'Flooring', 'factValue': 'Carpet, Hardwood, Tile'}, {'factLabel': 'Floor covering', 'factValue': 'Hardwood, Laminate, Wall to Wall Carpet'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Other Interior Features', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Addition size', 'factValue': '900'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Fireplace'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Ceiling Fan'}, {'factLabel': 'Features', 'factValue': 'Dbl Pane/Storm Windw, Dining Room, Security System, Ceiling Fan(s), Hot Tub/Spa'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Building', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Other Building Features', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Building info', 'factValue': 'Built On Lot'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Spaces and Amenities', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Size', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Unit count', 'factValue': '1'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Spaces', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Hot Tub/Spa'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Amenities', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Security System'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Construction', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Type and Style', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Structure type', 'factValue': 'Craftsman'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Single Family'}, {'factLabel': 'Architecture', 'factValue': 'Craftsman'}, {'factLabel': 'Entrance level', 'factValue': 'Main'}, {'factLabel': 'Style', 'factValue': '16 - 1 Story w/Bsmnt.'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Materials', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Roof type', 'factValue': 'Composition'}, {'factLabel': 'Exterior material', 'factValue': 'Wood'}, {'factLabel': 'Roof', 'factValue': 'Composition'}, {'factLabel': 'Foundation', 'factValue': 'Poured Concrete'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Dates', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Built in 1916'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Other Construction Features', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Stories', 'factValue': '1'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Exterior Features', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Patio', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Deck'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Yard', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Fenced Yard'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Garden'}]}, {'categoryName': 'View Type', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'View', 'factValue': 'Mountain'}, {'factLabel': 'View', 'factValue': 'Territorial, See Remarks'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Lot', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Lot', 'factValue': '4,000 sqft'}, {'factLabel': 'Lot topography/vegetation', 'factValue': 'Level, Steep Slope'}, {'factLabel': 'Lot details', 'factValue': 'Paved Street, Sidewalk, Curbs'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Other Exterior Features', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Parcel #', 'factValue': '6610001005'}, {'factLabel': 'Exterior', 'factValue': 'Wood'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Community and Neighborhood', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Schools', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Elementary school', 'factValue': 'Buyer To Verify'}, {'factLabel': 'Middle school', 'factValue': 'Buyer To Verify'}, {'factLabel': 'High school', 'factValue': 'Buyer To Verify'}, {'factLabel': 'School district', 'factValue': 'Seattle'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Transportation', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Bus line nearby', 'factValue': 'Y'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Parking', 'categories': [{'categoryName': '', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Parking', 'factValue': 'Attached Garage, 1 space, 290 sqft garage'}, {'factLabel': 'Parking type', 'factValue': 'Garage-Attached, Off Street'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Utilities', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Utilities', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Cable Ready'}, {'factLabel': 'Sewer', 'factValue': 'Sewer Connected'}, {'factLabel': 'Water source', 'factValue': 'Public'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Green Energy', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Energy source', 'factValue': 'Natural Gas, Solar (Unspecified)'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Other', 'categories': [{'categoryName': '', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Last sold', 'factValue': 'Dec 2019 for $900,000'}, {'factLabel': 'Last sale price/sqft', 'factValue': '$435'}, {'factLabel': 'Property type', 'factValue': 'RESI'}, {'factLabel': 'Possesion', 'factValue': 'Closing'}, {'factLabel': 'Form 17', 'factValue': 'Provided'}, {'factLabel': 'Potential terms', 'factValue': 'Cash Out, Conventional'}, {'factLabel': 'Site features', 'factValue': 'Cable TV, Deck, Fenced-Partially, Gas Available, Hot Tub/Spa'}, {'factLabel': 'Offers', 'factValue': 'Reviewed on receipt'}, {'factLabel': 'Commission', 'factValue': '2.5%'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Activity On Zillow', 'categories': [{'categoryName': '', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Views since listing', 'factValue': '77'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': '1 shopper saved this home'}]}]}]
name = "property in somewhere"
rows = {'name': name, 'interior_features':'N/A', 'space_amenities':'N/A', 'imaginary_stuff':'N/A'}

for elem in desc:
    if elem['categoryGroupName']=='Interior Features':
        interior_features = {curr['factLabel']: curr['factValue'] for i in elem['categories'] for curr in i['categoryFacts']}
        interior_features = str(interior_features).replace("{","").replace("}","").replace("'","")
        rows['interior_features'] = interior_features

    if elem['categoryGroupName']=='Imaginary Stuff':
        imaginary_stuff = {curr['factLabel']: curr['factValue'] for i in elem['categories'] for curr in i['categoryFacts']}
        imaginary_stuff = str(imaginary_stuff).replace("{","").replace("}","").replace("'","")   
        rows['imaginary_stuff'] = imaginary_stuff

    if elem['categoryGroupName']=='Spaces and Amenities':
        space_amenities = {curr['factLabel']: curr['factValue'] for i in elem['categories'] for curr in i['categoryFacts']}
        space_amenities = str(space_amenities).replace("{","").replace("}","").replace("'","")
        rows['space_amenities'] = space_amenities 

print(rows)
```

However, if a value occurs more than once, there may be a problem with the above code because it will only store the last value. in that case, we can use empty lists as values for the `rows` dictionary. Then append the values found in the `desc` list. Finally, if a list has values join them in a string, if not replace the empty list with 'N/A'.

```
desc = [{'categoryGroupName': 'Interior Features', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Bedrooms', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Beds', 'factValue': '3'}, {'factLabel': 'Master bedroom location', 'factValue': 'Main'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Kitchen', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Kitchen location', 'factValue': 'Main'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Other Rooms', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Dining room location', 'factValue': 'Main'}, {'factLabel': 'Living room location', 'factValue': 'Main'}, {'factLabel': 'Utility room location', 'factValue': 'Lower'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Heating and Cooling', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Heating', 'factValue': 'Forced air'}, {'factLabel': 'Heating', 'factValue': 'Gas'}, {'factLabel': 'Heating and cooling', 'factValue': '90%+ High Efficiency, Forced Air'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Basement', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Partially finished'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': '900 sqft basement'}, {'factLabel': 'Basement', 'factValue': 'Partially Finished'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Attic', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Attic'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Appliances', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Appliances included', 'factValue': 'Dishwasher, Dryer, Microwave, Range / Oven, Refrigerator, Washer'}, {'factLabel': 'Appliances that stay', 'factValue': 'Range/Oven, Dishwasher, Refrigerator, Washer, Dryer'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Flooring', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Floor size', 'factValue': '2,070 sqft'}, {'factLabel': 'Flooring', 'factValue': 'Carpet, Hardwood, Tile'}, {'factLabel': 'Floor covering', 'factValue': 'Hardwood, Laminate, Wall to Wall Carpet'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Other Interior Features', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Addition size', 'factValue': '900'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Fireplace'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Ceiling Fan'}, {'factLabel': 'Features', 'factValue': 'Dbl Pane/Storm Windw, Dining Room, Security System, Ceiling Fan(s), Hot Tub/Spa'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Building', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Other Building Features', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Building info', 'factValue': 'Built On Lot'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Spaces and Amenities', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Size', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Unit count', 'factValue': '1'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Spaces', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Hot Tub/Spa'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Amenities', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Security System'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Construction', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Type and Style', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Structure type', 'factValue': 'Craftsman'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Single Family'}, {'factLabel': 'Architecture', 'factValue': 'Craftsman'}, {'factLabel': 'Entrance level', 'factValue': 'Main'}, {'factLabel': 'Style', 'factValue': '16 - 1 Story w/Bsmnt.'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Materials', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Roof type', 'factValue': 'Composition'}, {'factLabel': 'Exterior material', 'factValue': 'Wood'}, {'factLabel': 'Roof', 'factValue': 'Composition'}, {'factLabel': 'Foundation', 'factValue': 'Poured Concrete'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Dates', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Built in 1916'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Other Construction Features', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Stories', 'factValue': '1'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Exterior Features', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Patio', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Deck'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Yard', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Fenced Yard'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Garden'}]}, {'categoryName': 'View Type', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'View', 'factValue': 'Mountain'}, {'factLabel': 'View', 'factValue': 'Territorial, See Remarks'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Lot', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Lot', 'factValue': '4,000 sqft'}, {'factLabel': 'Lot topography/vegetation', 'factValue': 'Level, Steep Slope'}, {'factLabel': 'Lot details', 'factValue': 'Paved Street, Sidewalk, Curbs'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Other Exterior Features', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Parcel #', 'factValue': '6610001005'}, {'factLabel': 'Exterior', 'factValue': 'Wood'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Community and Neighborhood', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Schools', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Elementary school', 'factValue': 'Buyer To Verify'}, {'factLabel': 'Middle school', 'factValue': 'Buyer To Verify'}, {'factLabel': 'High school', 'factValue': 'Buyer To Verify'}, {'factLabel': 'School district', 'factValue': 'Seattle'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Transportation', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Bus line nearby', 'factValue': 'Y'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Parking', 'categories': [{'categoryName': '', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Parking', 'factValue': 'Attached Garage, 1 space, 290 sqft garage'}, {'factLabel': 'Parking type', 'factValue': 'Garage-Attached, Off Street'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Utilities', 'categories': [{'categoryName': 'Utilities', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': None, 'factValue': 'Cable Ready'}, {'factLabel': 'Sewer', 'factValue': 'Sewer Connected'}, {'factLabel': 'Water source', 'factValue': 'Public'}]}, {'categoryName': 'Green Energy', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Energy source', 'factValue': 'Natural Gas, Solar (Unspecified)'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Other', 'categories': [{'categoryName': '', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Last sold', 'factValue': 'Dec 2019 for $900,000'}, {'factLabel': 'Last sale price/sqft', 'factValue': '$435'}, {'factLabel': 'Property type', 'factValue': 'RESI'}, {'factLabel': 'Possesion', 'factValue': 'Closing'}, {'factLabel': 'Form 17', 'factValue': 'Provided'}, {'factLabel': 'Potential terms', 'factValue': 'Cash Out, Conventional'}, {'factLabel': 'Site features', 'factValue': 'Cable TV, Deck, Fenced-Partially, Gas Available, Hot Tub/Spa'}, {'factLabel': 'Offers', 'factValue': 'Reviewed on receipt'}, {'factLabel': 'Commission', 'factValue': '2.5%'}]}]}, {'categoryGroupName': 'Activity On Zillow', 'categories': [{'categoryName': '', 'categoryFacts': [{'factLabel': 'Views since listing', 'factValue': '77'}, {'factLabel': None, 'factValue': '1 shopper saved this home'}]}]}]
name = "property in somewhere"
rows = {'name': name, 'interior_features':[], 'space_amenities':[], 'imaginary_stuff':[]}

for elem in desc:
    if elem['categoryGroupName']=='Interior Features' or elem['categoryGroupName']== 'Spaces and Amenities':
        interior_features = {curr['factLabel']: curr['factValue'] for i in elem['categories'] for curr in i['categoryFacts']}
        interior_features = str(interior_features).replace("{","").replace("}","").replace("'","")
        rows['interior_features'].append(interior_features)

    if elem['categoryGroupName']=='Imaginary Stuff':
        imaginary_stuff = {curr['factLabel']: curr['factValue'] for i in elem['categories'] for curr in i['categoryFacts']}
        imaginary_stuff = str(imaginary_stuff).replace("{","").replace("}","").replace("'","")   
        rows['imaginary_stuff'].append(imaginary_stuff)

    if elem['categoryGroupName']=='Spaces and Amenities':
        space_amenities = {curr['factLabel']: curr['factValue'] for i in elem['categories'] for curr in i['categoryFacts']}
        space_amenities = str(space_amenities).replace("{","").replace("}","").replace("'","")
        rows['space_amenities'].append(space_amenities)


separator = ' | '
rows = {k: separator.join(v) if v else 'N/A' for k,v in rows.items()}
print(rows)
```

If you wish to convert the `rows` dictionary to a list, you can use `rows.values()`. You can also use `csv.DictWriter()` so you can write the results to file, without having to convert it to list.

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, rows.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(rows)
```

Comment: Finally I've been able to persuade you to write an answer in a python question. Stay cool until the next trouble.

Comment: Ha! Best wishes for 2020!

Comment: Same to you. Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to ask a very unrelated question. Did you have option to dig deep in scrapy yet?

Comment: No, I don't use scrapy at all. Now, I have a question too. Is it possible for a value to occur more than once in the `desc` list? If so there may be a problem with my code because the `rows` key will have the last value only.

Comment: Yes, it is posiible for the sub values in the list to be present twice with the same name but not very frequently. I'm interested in this key `categoryGroupName` which is unique. However, I can live with some flaws.

Comment: I've tried to fix this issue with lists in the dictionary. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Hi @t.m.adam, hope you are doing good. I would love to see your valuable insight on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67985573/cant-figure-out-the-right-way-to-use-rotation-of-proxies-within-a-script?noredirect=1#comment120167254_67985573). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two mods of your code:

(1) Left justify each field based upon max-width of each column

(2) Don't print categories that don't match the ones desired (i.e. that return empy features)

```
def features(elem):
    " Gets features (interior and space) for current element "
    if elem['categoryGroupName']=='Interior Features':
            interior_features = {curr['factLabel']: curr['factValue'] for i in elem['categories'] for curr in i['categoryFacts']}
            interior_features = str(interior_features).replace("{","").replace("}","").replace("'","")
    else:
        interior_features = ""

    if elem['categoryGroupName']=='Spaces and Amenities':
            space_amenities = {curr['factLabel']: curr['factValue'] for i in elem['categories'] for curr in i['categoryFacts']}
            space_amenities = str(space_amenities).replace("{","").replace("}","").replace("'","")
    else:
        space_amenities = ""

    return interior_features, space_amenities

def format_data(row, col_widths):
    " Format row data so it has the right column width "
    # align based upon max width of each column
    # columns are tab separated so this can act as a CSV file
    return "/t".join(word.ljust(col_widths[i]) for i, word in enumerate(row))

# Widths to use for fields
feature_widths = [list(map(len, features(elem))) for elem in desc]
field0_max = len('property in somewhere')
field1_max = max(i[0] for i in feature_widths)
field2_max = max(i[1] for i in feature_widths)
col_widths = [field0_max+2, field1_max + 2, field2_max+2]

# Print header
with open('test.txt', 'w') as txtfile:
    # Write header
    row = ["property in somewhere", 'interior_features', 'space_amenities']
    s = format_data(row, col_widths)
    print(s)  # to stdout
    txtfile.write(s) # to file
    txtfile.write("\n")

    for elem in desc:
        interior_features, space_amenities = features(elem)
        if interior_features or space_amenities: # only write elements with features
            row = ["property in somewhere", interior_features, space_amenities]
            s = format_data(row, col_widths)
            print(s)  # to stdout
            txtfile.write(s) # to file
            txtfile.write("\n")
```

**Output**

```
property in somewhere   interior_features                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   space_amenities                       
property in somewhere   Appliances included: Dishwasher, Dryer, Microwave, Range / Oven, Refrigerator, Washer, Appliances that stay: Range/Oven, Dishwasher, Refrigerator, Washer, Dryer, Master bedroom location: Main, Dining room location: Main, Heating and cooling: 90%+ High Efficiency, Forced Air, Features: Dbl Pane/Storm Windw, Dining Room, Security System, Ceiling Fan(s), Hot Tub/Spa, Heating: Gas, Floor size: 2,070 sqft, Utility room location: Lower, Living room location: Main, Addition size: 900, Beds: 3, Basement: Partially Finished, Flooring: Carpet, Hardwood, Tile, None: Ceiling Fan, Floor covering: Hardwood, Laminate, Wall to Wall Carpet, Kitchen location: Main                                            
property in somewhere                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       None: Security System, Unit count: 1
```

Comment: You certainly did misunderstand the output I was expecting. Check out the edit for csv output. I never said that the way I parsed the fields are ideal way of doing that. Given that the parsing logic can always be rectified to strip those tabs and spaces if better logic comes along. Thanks.

Comment: @robots.txt--thanks for the clarification.  I modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: @robots.txt--the misunderstanding was you called this a CSV file, which normally does not require the text to be aligned for display (i.e. a tab for instance can be used to identify each field). I place a tab between fields so it can still be procesed as a CSV despite all the extra space to make it column aligned.